# azure pipelines are triggering when they are not supposed to trigger, how to stop them from triggering?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am struggling to figure out why pipelines are triggered when they are not supposed to.

I have two yaml files.

1. Main-Build.yml - which builds the project and creates artifacts
2. Test.yml - which uses "`resources: pipelines`"  to pull artifacts created in the build pipeline and executes the test. this test.yml files is used in 15 different pipelines with different variables to run 15 different tests throughout the week. (at least that's the idea)

content of test.yml

```
...
pr: none
trigger: none
...
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Main-Build
    source: Main-Build
    branch: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}
...
```

no other triggers are mentioned in the yaml.

only scheduled trigger is enabled in the pipeline:

[image]

but Test.yml pipelines still being triggered on completion of Main-Build pipeline.
as well as scheduled tests are still being trigger.

How do I stop them from triggering after the first pipeline?

I have tried with `trigger: none`, `trigger: true` removing triggers,
tried with pipeline triggers enabled, disabled.
nothing seems to help.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Main-Build
    source: Main-Build
    trigger: none
```